# How to use JSDoc and ts-check with a vanilla JavaScript constructor that returns a value directly?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, javascript-objects, jsdoc

Using vanilla JavaScript, I want to code a constructor that creates its instances by returning an object instead of using `this`. As explained [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new#description):

> Normally constructors don't return a value, but they can choose to do so to override the normal object creation process.

I want the code to use JSDoc along with `//@ts-check` to enforce some typing in VSCode.

Here's the code:

```
//@ts-check
/**
 * @constructor
 * @param {string} firstName
 * @property {function} innerSayHello - Logs a greeting.
 * @property {string} firstName - the Peep's first name
 */
var Peep = function (firstName) {
    "use strict";
    var peep = {};
    peep.firstName = firstName;

    peep.innerSayHello = function () {
        console.log("Hello, I'm " + peep.firstName + ".");
    };

    return peep;
};

var peep = new Peep("test");
console.log(peep.firstName);
peep.innerSayHello();
```

That seems to be what ts-check wants until I get to using the instance I've created; I get errors on `peep.firstName` and `peep.innerSayHello`. Those get these errors reported:

- Property 'firstName' does not exist on type 'Peep'.
- Property 'innerSayHello' does not exist on type 'Peep'.

When I mouse over `new Peep` in VSCode, I see the autocomplete I'd expect.

[image: screenshot of code, above, in VSCode, with red squiggles under the two property usages mentioned above, but also with a hover window saying that Peeps have two properties with descriptions that match the property usages exactly]

I realize what's happening, I think. Those two are marked as properties of the *constructor function* called `Peep` and not the object type that's returned. It seems to be ignoring the `=> Peep` part of the mouseover window. That is, I'm not sure how to say "This constructor creates objects that look like XYZ".

I've also tried with type definitions like this in case it's the "missing" `@returns` that's the trouble...

```
//@ts-check
/**
 * A person, colloquailly named.
 * @typedef {Object} PeepType
 * @property {function} innerSayHello - Logs a greeting.
 * @property {string} firstName - the Peep's first name
 */

/**
 * @constructor
 * @param {string} firstName
 * @returns {PeepType}
 */
var Peep = function (firstName) {
    "use strict";
    var peep = {};
    peep.firstName = firstName;

    peep.innerSayHello = function () {
        console.log("Hello, I'm " + peep.firstName + ".");
    };

    return peep;
};

var peep = new Peep("test");
console.log(peep.firstName);
peep.innerSayHello();
```

That tells me `@returns` is not doing what I want, but I'm not sure what I do want to use here.

---

It seems to work fine if you use the other mode of creating a constructor. Here's a decent example [from an old TypeScript bug report](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15959) that works now:

```
//@ts-check
var Person = function (firstNameOrPojo, lastName) {

    if (typeof firstNameOrPojo === "string") {
        this.firstName = firstNameOrPojo;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    } else {
        return new Person(firstNameOrPojo.firstName, firstNameOrPojo.lastName);
    }
};

Person.prototype.greet = function greet() {
    return `Hello, I am ${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}.`;
};

var fred = new Person({firstName: "Fred", lastName: "Flintstone"});

console.log(fred.greet());
```

No problems reported by ts-check. `fred` even has nice autocomplete with `firstName`, `lastName` and `greet`.

[image: autocomplete for fred shown]

But sure enough, if you turn that into constructor that returns a value, complaints again ensue, even without `ts-check`.

```
var Person = function (firstNameOrPojo, lastName) {
    var obj = {};
    if (typeof firstNameOrPojo === "string") {
        obj.firstName = firstNameOrPojo;
        obj.lastName = lastName;
        obj.greet = function greet() {
            return `Hello, I am ${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}.`;
        };

        return obj;
    }

    return new Person(firstNameOrPojo.firstName, firstNameOrPojo.lastName);
};

var fred = new Person({ firstName: "Fred", lastName: "Flintstone" });

console.log(fred.greet());
```

Though now the complaint is, since there's no `@constructor` directive, `Only a void function can be called with the 'new' keyword.`

How can I use JSDoc with this [valid] method of instance construction via returning a value?

Comment: What version of javascript are you targeting? Since you don't have to build your classes like this anymore in ES6.

Comment: @Leroy The version is devs who are [overly?] used to best practices in es5. And look, god help anyone supporting IE without transpilation (which includes me, me at the job I have now), but [this would work there and essentially everywhere](https://caniuse.com/?search=class). And it's not like this method has been marked obsolete -- it's just different than `class`. My question is why doesn't this valid instance construction work in ts-check-land and my suspicion is that this is a bug of oversight.